# How do I get a digital signal from a switch?

Tags: power-supply, switches, relay, home-automation, ac-dc

I want to essentially drive a relay using a switch. For eg: If the switch (AC Voltage : 220v, 50Hz) is switched on, it sends a digital signal to the relay to switch off.

Comment: ... You wouldn't. You'd use it to control the relay directly.

Comment: It might be worth adding a diagram of what you have in mind. You can for example get relays where the coil can be connected to 220 VAC.

Comment: Is your switch not rated to handle 220V or the relay's rated current?

Answer (score 1):

Use a 220v relay with a normally-closed contact.  The switch energizes the coil, which opens the contact.

I would look for an industrial supply company.  They can sell you a DPDT "ice cube" relay that has:

- an 8-pin socket (so you can replace it later without rewiring)
- a coil rated for 220v
- 2 independent sets of contacts that move together: each contact has a common (C), normally-open (NO), and normally-closed (NC) terminal.

When the relay is off, NC connects to C and NO connects to nothing.  When the relay is on, NO connects to C and NC connects to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different aspects of the circuit here... the 1st thing you want to do is detect a press and de-bounce it. If you do not want to write code you might want to get an SR latch (or make one from two NAND gates) - these are available for cheap in DIP packages. You might also want to run the switch into the latch through an RC LPF tuned to a low freq. like a few Hz.

Another solution is to use (at least) two stages of Schmidt triggers in series. That should condition your signal fine together with the RC filter.

Regarding the relay driving, you should check if the specific logic device you use have enough drive for the relay coil. If not you might want to use a BJT switch (just saturate the transistor in ON state).

You'll also need a diode in parallel with the coil to prevent back EMF from killing your logic quickly!

Comment: Mechanical switches controlling relay coils generally don't need to be debounced.  They just can't react that fast.  Logic chips can, but if there's no memory involved, that hardly matters either.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a relay with a coil that operates at 220VAC like this one: http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/RT314730/PB962-ND/1095286. Then, when you close the switch, the coil will be energized, and the switch will close. However, if you use the normally closed contact, your device will be powered when the relay is not energized, and turned off when the really is energized.

Really, though, just finding a SPDT switch that can handle the voltage and current is probably your best bet.

However, if you already have a relay, MCU, and/or other components picked out and at your disposal, @user34920's answer provides a good digital solution.

Answer (score -7):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faclHf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This seems like a solution. You could detect when the switch is flipped using a microcontroller and then sent the digital signal to turn on a relay to allow the 220V to pass.

Comment: "This seems like a solution." Right up until you fry the output.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that would entirely depend on the components.

Comment: I would not trust a MCU output to be able to either source enough current for a relay or to withstand the EMF generated by switching it off.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I fixed the EMF issue...now its entirely a component issue. :)

Comment: That's not how to correct it. The flyback diode must be across the inductive load, reverse biased.

Comment: FIX the schematic, or if you don't know how just delete the answer.

Comment: @user34920 I'm bet the author would get more out of my schematic then your answer...so simplify your answer or if you don't know how just delete it.

Comment: @tman no offense man but people voted your answer down on the case of being incorrect and oversimplified. If the OP wants more detail on my answer he can Google or ask here and I will be happy to help. But he better ask someone who knows what he is saying, you know what I mean?